# How does the data-binding features of WPF fit in with Entity Framework?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I'm aware that one of the advantages of WPF is it's data-binding capabilities.

How does this data-binding fit in with the Entity Framework?

Comment: Just as it fits in with any POCO objects. Not sure what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are getting at here. If your entity implements INotifyPropertyChanged and you fire PropertyChanged events accordingly from your entity then you get updates to your values when bound, but this is **NOT** Entity Framework specific.